# Is there an app skeleton builder for Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I was using DroidDraw, working through the tutorials. Looking at the resulting XML and the Java code to tie them together, I was thinking that I could build a program to automate that process, so I started noodling something together. But before I go off and totally remake the wheel, I was wondering if something like this hasn't already been made before?

I'm thinking of something that takes the layout XML from DroidDraw, and outputs a Java application that works, and is ready for you to add your own code.

It *seems* pretty basic, has it been done and I've just not spotted it? I've tried Google searches, but I don't see anything similar.

Comment: You mean it should produce the Java code or the XML?

Comment: Given the XML from DroidDraw, it should produce Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in UI editor that comes with Eclipse used to be pretty crappy - however, it's now getting better and better. Rev 11, which is coming out soon will a lot of new and useful features also.
Give it a try - I think you'll find this is the best tool.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting XML file you can take from DroidDraw requires no Java code.. you simply `setContentView(R.layout.name)` and that's it!

Just use IntelliJ or Eclipse to set up a skeleton project for you, and import the XML you created via DroidDraw.

Answer (score 0):

There is [App Inventor](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/). I have not tried it myself but it sounds pretty much like what you want.

As far as I know it is a very *visual* approach to develop an application.